# Transferring JSON variable between Classes

Tags: ios, json, swift

I managed to get my JSON variable in a variable in the new class through the following function:

```
class GamesOverview: Interface, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "presentGame") {
            var presentGame = segue.destinationViewController as! Game;
            presentGame.gameState = self.gameState;
            println(presentGame.gameState); 
        }
    }
}
```

However when I run viewDidLoad in the next class the variable self.gameState is not yet filled. It does however get filled the 2nd time I enter the class:

```
class Game: Interface{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();
        println(self.gameState!);
    }
}
```

Why isn't the self.GameState! filled at the first time? And how do I fix this?

Comment: Override viewWillAppear instead.

Comment: Try debugging application: set breakpoint on `println(presentGame.gameState); ` and make sure it is running. If not, set segue identifier in storyboard.

Comment: I tried viewWillAppear but it doesn't solve the problem. I'm sure println(presentGame.gameState); is running The segue identifier is set in the storyboard.